# How to return the data received from PageSpeed Insight from node in a route?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I am using the PSI npm package in a simple route. 
https://github.com/addyosmani/psi
Used the psi method from the library. However, the script does not wait for the expected result. It works Ok in console. However, I need to return the response to browser and display it there. How can I do this?
Note: psi method a Promise.

```
app.get('/psi', function(req, res){
    res.type('text/html');
    return psi('example.com',{ key: '*Iz*Sy*****PiZ***wz7****sy*****', strategy: 'desktop'}).then( data => {
        console.log('Speed score: ' + data.ruleGroup.SPEED.score);
        console.log('done');
        res.json({ 'results' : data.ruleGroup.SPEED.score });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but shouldn't you remove the `return` statement? If `psi` returns a promise and you return `psi` I believe the `.then()` statement should be added after the `app.get` function since it's returned there, but then you can't access `res`. So, try simply removing `return`?

Comment: Yes, I eventually removed it and now the results are showing up. However, I think I will need to make this request an Ajax one. So, is there a way I can return it after working with the data and return the derived results?

Comment: I believe that your solution with `res.json` should work, doesn't it? If it doesn't work it's probably because you need to add some settings to `app.use` or add some headers. Try logging the responses that you are trying to send and check so they have a correct format etc.